# How do I reference an additional repository in a stage condition in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm writing an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline that is stored in one repository and checks out an additional repository. What syntax do I need to use to write a condition using the additional repository?

The branch of the repo containing the YAML doesn't matter, just the additional repo.

This is a stripped down version of my pipeline:

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: myrepo
      type: github
      endpoint: my-endpoint
      name: org/myrepo
      trigger:
        - dev
        - release/release-*

stages:
  # ...
  - stage: DeployDevelopment
    displayName: Deploy to development
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(resources.repositories['myrepo'].ref, 'refs/heads/dev'))
    jobs: # ...
```

I've tried the following and they give me syntax errors when trying to run the pipeline:

- `eq(resources.repositories['myrepo'].ref, 'refs/heads/dev')`
- `eq($[resources.repositories['myrepo'].ref], 'refs/heads/dev')`
- `eq($[[resources.repositories['myrepo'].ref]], 'refs/heads/dev')`
- `eq(${{resources.repositories['myrepo'].ref}}, 'refs/heads/dev')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ref name of the resource repo, you can use the following format:

`$[ resources.repositories['other'].ref ]`

Refer to this doc: [Repository details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details)

When you set the variable in condition field, you can define the pipeline variable to get the ref name first. Then it will work.

```
variables:
  tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['Reponame'].ref ]
```

Here is an example：

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository
    type: git
    name: net5project/reponame

variables:
   tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['MyAzureReposGitRepository'].ref ]
  
stages:
  - stage: test
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['tools.ref'], 'refs/heads/main'))
    jobs:
      - job: test1
        steps:
          - script:  echo $(tools.ref)
```

Comment: I tried `$[]`, but I think what tripped me up was *needing* to use a variable instead of accessing `resources.repositories` in the condition. I would find the docs more helpful if there was an reference page listing every "latent" object like `resources` and `variables`, and whether each is available in compile-time or runtime expressions.